# IsTornPageProtectionOn in Visual Studio Database Edition GDR

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, gdr

im having major issues trying to mirror our newly upgrade database solution (to GDR)... specifically the database project settings.

when i run a schema compare, i get differences on the IsTornPageProtectionOn variable, however when I go to the settings of the database project this setting is nowhere to be found!

i have tried googling for any sort of reference to this property in the visual studio 2k8 UI, however i cant find anything. only a bunch of obscure references on the msdn site, which dont say anything in regards to the ui.

if someone could point me in the right direction i would greatly appreciate it.

i am using sql server 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out an (obvious) workaround to this...
i simply edited the database settings file (the Database.sqlsettings file) in notepad and changed the setting via there. much easier :)

although if someone DOES still know where to change it from in the UI, i would appreciate it if you left a comment :)